# Which applications are using internet

Tags: internet, installed-programs, lsof

How can I check which applications are using internet?
How to block internet accessing one particular application?
Is there any GUI tool that exist for it in Ubuntu Software Centre?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need something like a firewall? Try `gUFW` from the Software Center.

Comment: It is probably not possible to block a specific application without resorting to serious command-line geekery. You can use `trickler` from software center to **limit** an application's bandwidth usage, but it is also a command-line utility (use like: `alt+F2` and enter `trickler -d 1 -u 1 application`).

Comment: it is trickle not trickler

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`lsof -i` will list the applications that are accessing the network. There are some helpful examples in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) but you might also want to look at [Track network connections with LSOF on Linux](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/track-network-connections-with-lsof-on-linux/1049412).

Answer (score 10):

I found very useful next command that show only the names of applications that use internet connection (create internet traffic) at the moment:

```
netstat -lantp | grep -i stab | awk -F/ '{print $2 $3}' | sort | uniq
```

<sup>Source: [Show apps that use internet connection at the moment (Multi-Language).](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3542/show-apps-that-use-internet-connection-at-the-moment.-multi-language)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

To see which application is using data, try the [NetHogs](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs) application from the eponymous package `nethogs` in Ubuntu’s “Universe” repository or from source.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `lsof -i` which will list applications that have open network sockets as Richard mentioned, you can also install `ufw` and `gufw` which are the [Uncomplicated FireWall](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/gufw-simple-gui-for-ufw-uncomplicated-firewall.html) and the GUI program that manages it. I haven't used either of these since 8.04 since I mostly use ubuntu internal to my own network, but they should have options for that. [`iptables`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) is also a very popular firewall.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of listening applications by using UFW using the following command.

```
sudo ufw show listening
```